# Tailwind not rendering certain background colors

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a home page component (I am using React) from tailwind which has this suggestion:

````
{/*
     This example requires updating your template:

     ```
     <html class="h-full bg-gray-900">
     <body class="h-full">
     ```
*/}
````

I then changed my template (index.html) as required and it works, but it seems to not work other background colors that are lighter like `bg-gray-300` or `bg-amber-400` but works fine with `bg-gray-400` and anything that is very dark.

I tried on different devices (and browsers) and still saw the same behavior, does anyone know what's causing this?

Cheers

My tailwind import in the css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif, 'Inter';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

`bg-gray-300` and `bg-amber-400` is working well at me.

I think you should use `className` instead on `class` in ReactJS.

And TailwindCSS class must be used internal children of `body` elements, not `html`.

I think you used Tailwind calsses in `index.html` in `public` folder.

Please try add that classes to root component in `src` folder.

Comment: The tailwind component I used requires that I add the colours to the template (index.html). This came directly from the library code. As for ‘className’, that is used in jsx/tsx files, the template is an html, just to reiterate, the comment to add the colour to the html tag in the template is a copy paste from the tailwind component that I used.